# armeabi-v7a with -mfloat-abi=hard

Tags: android, android-ndk, armv7

Per [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14955479/1172110) , I tried to build using the `-mfloat-abi=hard` flag.  In `Application.mk` I have

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard
```

and got this error

```
error: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/XXX.o uses VFP register arguments, output does not
```

I found [this link](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-building/124vyjdwyg/android-with-hardware-float/125163k72g#125163k72g) where someone posted that -mfloat-abi=hard *does not* work with the stock toolchain.

Is this still the case in NDKr9?

Comment: Is that error coming from the linker?  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846430/hard-float-calls-for-some-functions-in-gcc

Comment: Yes, linker error.  And your link/answer shed more light on this flag.  I was looking for some easy optimizations when targeting v7a, but that flag probably wouldn't have made much difference anyway.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried?

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a-hard
```

This seems to work in NDKr9