# Android NDK eabi - how to make ndk know to use hard fp?

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk, ld

I've prebuilt library (libxxx.so) with "-mfloat-abi=hard" parameter. Now i'd like to compile my native code with this lib and build shared lib (.so) with ndk.

Application.mk:

> APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a

Android.mk:

> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
> LOCAL_MODULE := xxx
>
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libxxx.so
>
> include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>   LOCAL_MODULE    := xxx_wrapper
>
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := xxx_wrapper.cpp xxx_wrapper.h
>
> LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := xxx
>
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /softdev/host/include/
>
> LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
>
> LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
>
> LOCAL_CXXFLAGS += -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard
>
> LOCAL_CFLAGS   += -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard
>
> include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

on `ndk-build` i'm getting an error:

> /softdev/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:
>   error:
>   /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/project/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/xxx_wrapper/xxx_wrapper.o
>   uses VFP register arguments, output does not
>   /softdev/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:
>   error:
>   /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/project/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libxxx.so
>   uses VFP register arguments, output does not collect2: ld returned 1
>   exit status

How can i fix it? Both .o files are hard-float according to output and i can't figure out what "output" means? I've added '-mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard' to my module description.

UPDATE: i've executed ndk-build V=1 and found no "-mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard" arguments in command-line, so i i've tried to do it manually (but still no result):

> ```
> mba-anton:build asmirnov$ /softdev/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
> ```
>
> -Wl,-soname,libxxx_wrapper.so -shared --sysroot=/softdev/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-8/arch-arm /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/xxx_jni/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/xxx_wrapper/xxx_wrapper.o
>   /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/xxx_jni/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libstdc++.a
>   -lgcc /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/xxx_jni/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libxxx.so
>   -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard  -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8  -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -L/softdev/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib -L/usr/lib -llog -lstdc++ -lc -lm -o /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/xxx_jni/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libxxx_wrapper.so
>       /softdev/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:
>   error:
>   /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/xxx_jni/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/xxx_wrapper/xxx_wrapper.o
>   uses VFP register arguments, output does not
>       /softdev/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:
>   error:
>   /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/xxx_jni/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libxxx.so
>   uses VFP register arguments, output does not
>       collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846430/hard-float-calls-for-some-functions-in-gcc/

Comment: yes. i did searched but there is no solution except words only.

Answer (score 1):

You may want this:
    -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp

In a word, "-mfloat-abi=hard" or "-mfloat-abi=softfp" argument does not refers to use hardware or software FPU.

Please see [Getting hardware floating point with android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004915/getting-hardware-floating-point-with-android-ndk) for more details, fadden has given a great and clear answer, so I won't bother to repeat it here.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

`APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a-hard`

instead of

`APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a`

Also you can add these flags in Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_CXXFLAGS  := -O2 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mhard-float -D_NDK_MATH_NO_SOFTFP=1 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -O2 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mhard-float -D_NDK_MATH_NO_SOFTFP=1 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard
LOCAL_LDFLAGS   := -lm_hard
```

Comment: If not using armeabi-v7a-hard, I needed to also add -Xlinker --no-warn-mismatch to LOCAL_LDFLAGS too.

Comment: No longer supported